# reading decimal numbers from UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a textfield that should accept decimal numbers; it should accept numbers with a comma (6,7) or a point (6.7) irrespective of the user's locale.

I use the following code:

```
    NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber* number = [formatter numberFromString:txtScore.text];
    NSDecimalNumber* decimalNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]  initWithDouble:[number doubleValue]];
```

The problem is that if I use a comma in the textfield, for some locales I always get back 0. The same is true for the point, some locales can read it, but others always return 0.

So, how can I get this textfield to work with both commas and points, irrespective of the user's locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a hack to solve this problem.

```
     NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSMutableString* scoreString = [txtScore.text mutableCopy];
[scoreString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"." options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [scoreString length])];
NSDecimalNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:scoreString locale:locale];    
[locale release];
```

I now replace every occurrence of a comma with a point and always use the en_US locale that works with a point.

This works, but I wonder if there is perhaps a more natural solution.

Comment: If you always use us-locale and do the replace manually, you can shorten that to `NSDecimalNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[txtScore.text replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the step with NSNumber inbetween. Simply use

```
number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string locale:userLocale];
```

You need the locale to differ between 3,000 and 3,000.10 (in other countries 3.000 and 3.000,10).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Can you show your code and add a NSLog() of the string you want to convert?

Comment: I am now using your code snippet given above. This problem can easily be reproduced by putting a textfield on a screen and filling in numbers like 7,8 or 7.8, and then converting the input to a decimal number. If you for example try this out with english and dutch, you will see that you get different output.

Comment: this method definitely doesn't work properly. I just went through a few examples (German locale) - no way.